# UmbracoAzureBlobStorage - Files lost after some times Using Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, azure-blob-storage

I have a project that uses a combination of these tools:

==================================

**Azure website**

**Azure Blob**

**Azure CDN**

**UmbracoAzureBlobStorage** - 1.0.10.5 - https://github.com/idseefeld/UmbracoAzureBlobStorage

**WindowsAzure.Storage** - 4.3.0

**Umbraco** - 7.2.5 assembly: 1.0.5610.18894

**idseefeld.de.UmbracoAzure** - 1.0.0.0
https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/azure-blob-storage-provider/

==================================

**config/FileSystemProviders.config**

```
<FileSystemProviders>

  <!-- Media -->
  <Provider alias="media"
      type="idseefeld.de.UmbracoAzure.AzureBlobFileSystem, idseefeld.de.UmbracoAzure">
    <Parameters>
      <add key="containerName" value="media" />
      <add key="rootUrl" value="http://az739977.vo.msecnd.net/" />
      <add key="connectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=XXX" />
    </Parameters>
  </Provider>

</FileSystemProviders>
```

==================================

The file upload is working as expected at start. But after sometime, and of course few uploads, it looks like our files are deleted from the blob and the CDN cannot serve them anymore.

Is there something I'm missing? I have almost the same configuration in another project and it's working as expected. I tried reinstalling the whole thing but the problem occurs everytimes.

https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/azure-blob-storage-provider/ show us configuration that point directly to the blob, not the CDN as I do. Should I take a look at this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uninstall-Pacakge UmbracoAzureBlobStorage
Uninstall-Package idseefeld.de.UmbracoAzure
Install-Package UmbracoAzureBlobStorage
```

Solved the problems. The project referenced the "idseefeld" DLL. It was kinda weird.